# Unable to get order details using magento 2 rest api

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, order-grid, rest-api

I have created an order in magento 2. And magento gave me this message

> "Your order number is: 000000235. We'll email you an order
>   confirmation with details and tracking info."

Screen shot is also attached,
[image]

Then I tried to fetch the order details using rest api endpoint `rest/V1/orders/235` in **salesOrderRepositoryV1** on http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/

My request as shown in screenshot,
[image]

but everytime i get this,

```
{
"message": "Requested entity doesn't exist"
}
```

Just for the reference screen shot of admin panel->sales->orders is also attached that i am fetching the details against the valid order id.

[image]

I investigated this isssue, here are some of my findings,

1. This is not happening with all the orders.
2. Its due to the difference between entity_id and increment_id in sales_order table.
3. For most of the old orders(those i created earlier) everything is working fine but for most recent orders this issue is occuring(for which i have different entity_id and increment_id(magento gives us this id at success page)
4. I need to pass in increment_id in `rest/V1/orders/{id}` but this endpoint point to entity_id in the sales_order table

Why i have difference in my entity_id and increment_id? In sales_order table i have same entity_id and increment_id for the first 165 orders(i.e entity_id = increment_id) then form entity_id 166 my increment_id became 179. Why this difference came in suddenly.

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Its not mandatory that **entity_id** of **sales_order** table and **increment_id** of **sales_order** table are **same**.

**entity_id** field should be auto incremented ,so it may be differ when you delete any specific order manually and its used as foreign key in **sales_order_item** table to **identify** how many items each order have.

Meanwhile you must need to pass increment_id with orders api , But your url should be like this **http://os.mydomain.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders/000000003**

here **000000003** this is my increment_id

Then pass **Authorization Bearer accesstoken** in headers

It will works for all orders.

Comment: I am doing the same for order 235(increment_id) as you can see in the screen shot number 2, but i am getting { "message": "Requested entity doesn't exist" }. I am doing exactly what you mentioned or am i doing something wrong? please refer to the screenshots attached with the question.

Comment: No, like this, os.mydomain.com/rest/V1/orders/235. You can see screenshot number 2 for reference. What is this index.php in your url?

Comment: I also tried https://os.mydomain.com/rest/V1/orders/000000235 and https://os.mydomain.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders/000000235 too, but it still says  { "message": "Requested entity doesn't exist" }. I know the issue, /rest/V1/orders/ searches for order in sales_order table by entity_id. But it should search order by increment_id. To reproduce this issue, your increment_id and entity_id have to different.

Comment: And i am sure no one deleted the records from my sales_order table manually, because my entity_id is consistent, as you said its auto increment so if some one would have deleted records from the table manually so i should have in consistent entity_id in sales_order table, but thats not the case.

Comment: And leading zeros are not the issue, whether we include them or not, it does not matter, i have been using order id without leading zeros in various places, it works absolutely fine. This looks like a magento 2 REST API bug to me. But i am not sure how to reproduce it. Do you know how increment_id is generated in magento backend?

Comment: And entity_id is of type integer, that is why leading zeros does not matter, but you are right it would matter in increment_id because its of type string. But /rest/V1/orders/ searches the order by entity_id according to my finding. In your case increment_id and entity_id should be same. You can try it without leading zeros at your end. It would work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63546/discussion-between-abdul-moiz-and-manthan-dave).